# Is Implement of operators in one instruction really faster than implement operators in separated instructions?

Tags: visual-c++

I tried to measure the speed of a simple code as below. The purpose is to find out which method will be faster (1 instruction x[j] = j * 2.0 + 1.0; OR 2 separated instructions x[j] = j * 2.0; x[j] += 1.0; ?)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x[100000];

    std::clock_t start;
    start = std::clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            x[j] = j * 2.0 + 1.0;
            //x[j] = j * 2.0;
            //x[j] += 1.0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << std::endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The results showed that with only 1 instruction (x[j] = j * 2.0 + 1.0;), it took me around 3.5(s). However, with 2 separated instructions (x[j] = j * 2.0; x[j] += 1.0;), it took me 8(s).

Could anyone explain why the difference of time is so big like that? Thanks in advance all.

Comment: Make sure you are measuring the Release build. It's pointless to talk about performance of an unoptimized Debug build.

Comment: Thank you. You're correct. With Release Mode, both ways pointed to the same performance.